# How can i check if the value for "_id" field exists and how to read, write, update and delete data based on it

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a discord bot for dealing with user notes. So the bot basically stores a string as a note in a list inside the database. The notes are user specific. I tried setting `ctx.author.id` as the value for "_id" field and then checking if the user id of the person using the command is equal to the value of "_id" in any document in the database. But it does not work.

Here is my code for the command:

```
@client.command()
async def makenotes(ctx, *, args):
    try:
        if (len(db.NoteBoyNotes.find_one({'_id':ctx.author.id})) == 0):
            NotesUpdateDict = {'_id':ctx.author.id, 'notes':[]}
            NotesUpdateDict['notes'].append(args)
            NBNotes.update(NotesUpdateDict)
            x = notesCol.insert_one(NBNotes)
            await ctx.send("Ok, Noted")
        else:
            pass
    except:
        await ctx.send("Some error occurred")
```

Can someone help with this? Another thing, I am using `motor` for `asyncio`, not `pymongo`.

**EDIT:** Here is the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkfH0.png)

Comment: I mean from the error you can see that your db.NoteBoyNotes.findone is an _asyncio.future and has no length...  I'm not sure what the code you posted has todo with that.

Comment: @kpie ```if (len(db.NoteBoyNotes.find_one({'_id':ctx.author.id})) == 0):``` This line is causing the error

Comment: Have you tried `if (len(await db.NoteBoyNotes.find_one({'_id':ctx.author.id})) == 0):`

Comment: @kpie No, lemme try

Comment: @kpie Same error

Comment: make it 2 lines: `temp = await db.NoteBoyNotes.find_one({'_id':ctx.author.id}))` then `if len(temp)==0` or use parentheses `if (len((await db.NoteBoyNotes).find_one({'_id':ctx.author.id})) == 0):`

Comment: PyMongo's `find_one` returns a matching document _or_ a `None` if there is no matching document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is from a comment posted by @kpie,

````
@client.command()
async def makenotes(ctx, *, args):
    try:
        check = await db.NoteBoyNotes.find_one({'_id':ctx.author.id})
        if (check is None):
            NotesUpdateDict = {'_id':ctx.author.id, 'notes':[]}
            NotesUpdateDict['notes'].append(args)
            NBNotes.update(NotesUpdateDict)
            x = notesCol.insert_one(NBNotes)
            await ctx.send("Ok, Noted")
        else:
            pass
    except:
        await ctx.send("Some error occurred")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
@client.command()
async def makenotes(ctx, *, args):
    try:
        check = awaut db.NoteBoyNotes.find_one({'_id':ctx.author.id})
        if (len(check) == 0):
            NotesUpdateDict = {'_id':ctx.author.id, 'notes':[]}
            NotesUpdateDict['notes'].append(args)
            NBNotes.update(NotesUpdateDict)
            x = notesCol.insert_one(NBNotes)
            await ctx.send("Ok, Noted")
        else:
            pass
    except:
        await ctx.send("Some error occurred")
```

Comment: I am getting the same error

Comment: Try this solution with `check = await db.NoteBoyNotes.find_one({'_id':ctx.author.id})`

Comment: and `if check is None:`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you post it as an answer so that i can upvote it and it can others in the future.

Comment: i edited my answer with what @kpie said

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await db.NoteBoyNotes.find_one` so that you get the returned value instead of the future.

Also I believe find one Returns a single document, or None if no matching document is found. so you check if check is None rather than len().